# Deleting images from a folder programmatically

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules

i want to delete images from public:// sub folder pro grammatically. i have paths like this below.

```
$path = 'http://localhost/Drupal/dbquery/sites/default/files/take_snap/20140713110549.jpg';
```

i want to delete like this,

```
$path = 'http://localhost/Drupal/dbquery/sites/default/files/take_snap/20140713110549.jpg';

$del = unlink($path);
```

but it doesn't delete image. i try to do this from menu call back function. how do i do that?.

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 7 you can use the [file_delete](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_delete/7) to delete the file and its DB records as well.

Answer (score 0):

these codes work. i just changed the path to relative path like below.

```
$path = 'sites/default/files/take_snap/20140713110549.jpg';

$del = unlink($path);
```

Now it deletes file from public sub folder.